# How do I retrieve the most recent screenshotfrom the Kubuntu clipboard?

Tags: clipboard

How do I retrieve the most recent screenshot from the Kubuntu clipboard? this is surely a very simple action, but it isn't obvious how todo it. A Google search comes up with complicated answers.There has to be a simple answer.

Answer (score 0):

Screenshots usually make a jpg image in `/home/user/Pictures`. Windows puts them on the clipboard.